# Passing multiple values from a page to another in Oracle APEX

Tags: url, parameter-passing, oracle-apex

I wish to know the way to pass multiple values from a page to another and being stored in session.

The current generated URL is:

```
https://server_name/apex/f?p=285:20:SESSION_ID::NO:20:P21_ACTIVITY_NAME:1:P20_USER_NAME:APEX_USER
```

Actually I wanted to pass `P21_ACTIVITY_NAME` and `P20_USER_NAME` to another page, but with the URL mentioned above, the value of `P21_ACTIVITY_NAME` in session is  1:P20_USER_NAME and value of `P20_USER_NAME` is `null`

Comment: By the way, really P21_ACTIVITY_NAME ? why not P20_ACTIVITY_NAME?

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Suppose names of your items (`P21_ACTIVITY_NAME` and `P20_USER_NAME`) follow the APEX item naming convention (`P<page_number>_<item name>`). In this case, when you are on a page `21`, values of items of page 20 in session state are `NULL`. Also, it is meaningless to set value of item on a page `21` when you go to page `20`. It is unclear now, what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your remind. I will make necessary corrections. But for my opition, the naming will not affect the result because it is working although I did not follow the naming convention.

Comment: Following the naming convention is intended to clarify your question. If you create an item with name `P21_ACTIVITY_NAME` on the page with number `20`, it is not a problem while you don't asking for a help. If I see name  `P21_ACTIVITY_NAME`, I suppose that item is situated on the page 21, and if it is on another page, you should say about it in the question. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is wrong.

Read https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017

Right syntax should be like this:

```
https://server_name/apex/f?p=285:20:SESSION_ID::NO:20:P21_ACTIVITY_NAME,P20_USER_NAME:1,APEX_USER
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And I found the best way is set the values into application items.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a global item in apex and setting the values of those items whenever you submit the page that sets the values? that way, you can refer to those items values in your whole session, from any page of your application.

I have another way of doing that using the browser's `sessionStorage`. If you're interested then here's how:

set the static ID property of the button of the page that will redirect your page to another page. For the sake of this example, i will set it to "submitbutton".
Then in the `Execute on Page Load` part of your page, enter the following lines:

```
    $("#submitbutton").mousedown(function(){
        sessionStorage.P20_ACTIVITY_NAME = $("#P20_ACTIVITY_NAME").val();
        sessionStorage.P20_USER_NAME = $("#P20_USER_NAME").val(); 
    });
```

You can refer to those values from another page through javascript like this:

```
sessionStorage.P20_ACTIVITY_NAME or sessionStorage.P20_USER_NAME
```

Here's an example:

```
document.getElementById("the_id_of_the_item_you_want_to_set_with_the_value_from_theotherpage").value = sessionStorage.P20_ACTIVITY_NAME;
```

the sample sets the value of the element in the current page from the value of the item from the previous page.

Comment: Seems like you're very expert in using JavaScript in Oracle APEX. Do you know how to apply JQuery in APEX? If yes then how to do? For example, where to place the codes.

Comment: @Jonas, you can either put it in the `Function and Global Declarations` part of your main page or in the `Execute on Page Load`. There's no need to declare the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` tag for jquery. Oracle APEX automatically declares it for you